# Accessing property of javascript object gives wrong value

Tags: javascript

Pls see the simplified code below. I observed that accessing the property xproducttype of userapp provides 2 different values - the initial (incorrect) value when accessing directly, and the (correct) value (set by some code later) when accessing via a function (getXproducttype). I dont understand why I dont get the right value when accessing the property directly(e.g.,userapp.xproducttype)? Only when I define a function (like getXproducttype) I get the right value (0 in example)...

The simplified code:

```
userapp = function(){ //module pattern
 //userapp properties 
 var xproducttype = 1000;

 var getXproducttype = function(){
   return xproducttype;
 }

 var ready = function(callback){
   //here - before callback()- xproducttype is set to 0 by some code; 
   //no further code changes xproducttype again (!)

   callback();
 };//ready()

 return{ xproducttype:xproducttype,
      getXproducttype:getXproducttype}
}(); //userapp = function(){


$(document).ready(function(){

  userapp.ready(function() {

    //between the next 2 console.log() code lines is no other code (!)
    console.log('userapp.xproducttype: '+userapp.xproducttype); //returns the initial (wrong!) value 1000
    console.log('userapp.getXproducttype(): '+userapp.getXproducttype()); //returns (correct!) value 0 set later

  });//userapp.ready(function()

}); //$(document).ready
```

Comment: can anybody explain how `userapp` gets `ready` method?

Comment: not sure whether I understand your question..ready() within userapp is just a defined method using a callback

Comment: the object returned by the anonymous function and assigned to `userapp` only has one property `xproducttype` and one method `getXproducttype` - in the code shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
return { xproducttype: xproducttype }
```

You've created a new, separate copy of it. The easiest solution is to always use the getter if possible. If not, you will need to stick xproducttype down inside an object and pass a reference to that object around.

Here is how to stick it inside an object:

```
var xproducttype = {
    value: 1000;
};

var getXproducttype = function() {
    return xproducttype.value;
};

return {
    xproducttype: xproducttype,
    getXproducttype: getXproducttype
};

userapp.ready(function() {
    // will now be the value you expect
    console.log('userapp.xproducttype: '+userapp.xproducttype.value);
});
```

JavaScript is always a pass by value language. The trick here is you are passing a reference to an object as your value. So you end up with two copies of the reference, that both point to the same object.

In other words: using an object in this case allows you to work with references instead of primitives.

Comment: thnx for your comment. Can you please elaborate on "If not, you will need to stick xproducttype down inside an object and pass a reference to that object around" - perhaps with an example?

Comment: sure, I added more to my answer

Comment: thnx for the further explennation (!)