# which of the 2 descriptions of module patterns to use?

Tags: javascript

Rephrasing this question: what's the difference between the following 2 descriptions below that describe a module pattern? Is description 1 also a module pattern? What happens when I invoke one or the other?

I started with description 2, with which I had a problem ([Accessing property of javascript object gives wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095368/accessing-property-of-javascript-object-gives-wrong-value)) and then rewrote the pattern to description 1 (at least, I assume description 1 still reflects a module pattern?) to experiment with an alternative solution for that problem.

I also noticed (using the descriptions in jsfiddle) that with description 1 I can access the property 'xproducttype' directly and with the earlier description 2 I need to use the solutions as suggested in [Accessing property of javascript object gives wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095368/accessing-property-of-javascript-object-gives-wrong-value).

Description 1 module pattern:

```
function userapp (){}; //module pattern
 //userapp properties 
 userapp.xproducttype = 1000;

 userapp.getXproducttype = function(){
   return this.xproducttype;
 };

userapp.ready = function(callback){
//here - before callback()- xproducttype is set to 0 by some code; 
//no further code changes xproducttype again (!)

callback();
 };//ready()
```

Description 2 module pattern - as used in problem [Accessing property of javascript object gives wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095368/accessing-property-of-javascript-object-gives-wrong-value)

```
userapp = function(){ //module pattern
 //userapp properties 
 var xproducttype = 1000;

 var getXproducttype = function(){
   return xproducttype;
 }

 var ready = function(callback){
   //here - before callback()- xproducttype is set to 0 by some code; 
   //no further code changes xproducttype again (!)

   callback();
 };//ready()

 return{ xproducttype:xproducttype,
  getXproducttype:getXproducttype}
}(); //userapp = function(){
```

Comment: `userapp.getXproducttype()` doesn't work in your first pattern. Please fix this before asking. Also, there's no reason that `userapp` is a no-op function - make it a simple object `{}`

Comment: @Bergi. Thnx. I fixed the method. I'm not sure I understand what you mean with: "Also, there's no reason that userapp is a no-op function - make it a simple object {}". To which of the 2 descriptions do you refer?

Comment: To the first - where it is a no-op :-)

Comment: the reason (which indeed I did not mention) for using this pattern is to simulate global static variables...

Answer (score 0):

> Description 1 module pattern: […]

This should really be rewritten to the equivalent

```
var userapp = {
  xproducttype: 1000,
  getXproducttype: function() {
    return this.xproducttype;
  },
  ready: function(callback) {
    // some code
    callback();
  }
};
```

> Is description 1 also a module pattern?

Yes, plain [object literals are one implementation of modules](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). There is however no reason to use an empty function as the base object.

> what's the difference between the following 2 descriptions below that describe a module pattern? What happens when I invoke one or the other?

In pattern 1, `xproducttype` is a public property of the module object and could be reassigned by anybody who wants to harm it. The getter is actually superfluous here. In pattern 2, `xproducttype` is a local variable only accessible to the functions in the module closure scope, i.e. `getXproductype` and `ready`. Direct access to it is prevented, it is only accessible via the getter method.

> I also noticed that with description 1 I can access the property 'xproducttype' directly and with the earlier description 2 I need to use the [getter as suggested in the answer to my previous question].

Yes, exactly that is the implication of the privateness given by the closure scope in the *module pattern* (and it's subpattern of [revealing modules](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)).

> the reason for using this pattern is to simulate global static variables...

There might be an easier way to do this. Object literals are fine for this, if you want to prevent that their properties are changed you can make them non-writable.

```
userapp = Object.freeze({
    xproducttype: 1000
    // …
});
Object.defineProperty(window /*the global object*/, "userapp" {
    writable: false, configurable: false
});
```

> before callback() xproducttype is set to 0 by some code; no further code changes xproducttype again (!)

That doesn't sound like something really static, but something that is initialised asynchronically. You might want to look at [promises](http://promisesaplus.com/) which seem to be perfect for this.